# find the maximum possible length of segments (a scan line algorithm)

Tags: algorithm

The segments (their beginnings) are given. Let them be: 1, 4, 6, 9, 10. All segments have the same length C. We need to find such a maximum length (C) that there is no such common point that belongs to N segments. For example, if N = 2, and the length of the segments above is 4 (C = 4), then if we sort the coordinates of the beginning of the segments and their ends, we get: [1, 5], [4, 8], [6, 10], [9, 13], [10, 14] (it is not difficult to notice that at point 10 ([6, 10], [9, 13], [10, 14]) we have 3 segments intersecting at once, which contradicts the condition)

I know the algorithm for fixed ends of segments, but I do not know how to choose such ends so that the common point contains no more than N without O(n^2) iterations. Please help me

Comment: In your example, if `N = 2` and `C = 4` isn't `5` already a point that belongs to 2 segments `[1,5], [4,8]`? In the problem statement you say `no such common point that belongs to N segments`, but the example implies `no such common point that belongs to more than N segments`.

Comment: On second thought, if the ends are exclusive then you can argue that `5` doesn't belong to the previous segment and `4` doesn't belong to the next segment. So for a valid overlap a full interval of length `2` must be shared by both segments so that we get one shared point. Is this how a common point is defined?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an `O(n)` time complexity algorithm, provided the beginnings of the segments are already sorted. The space complexity is `O(1)`.

Let's define what a shared point means in terms of the absolute distances between the segment beginnings.

```
segment beginnings = [1,_,_,4,_,_,_,8] # empty cells added for illustration
N = 2
if we take C = 5 we get [1,_,_,4,_,_,_,8]
                           1,2,3,4,5
It's evident that there is shared point. If we had C = 4,
this wouldn't be the case since the end points of the segments don't count.
```

So, we can state that for 2 segments to have at least one shared point, the length of `C` must be at least `abs(s_seg2 - s_seg1) + 2`. This is the distance of the segment starts plus 2. This also means that `C = abs(s_seg2 - s_seg1) + 1` avoids any common point between `seg1` and `seg2`

Now, the above implies that to avoid one shared point between any 2 segments (`N = 2`), `C` must be `min(abs(s_segi - s_segj))+1` for `0 <= i < len(segment_starts)-1, j = i+1`.

How do we generalize this idea to one shared point between 3 segments (`N = 3`) or any number of segments with `2 <= N <= len(segment_starts)`?

For 3 adjacent segments, `s_seg1, s_seg2, s_seg3` to produce one shared point between the 3, the length of `C` must be `abs(s_seg3 - s_seg1)+2`, so `+1` would be the maximum possible length of `C`.

The above motivates the following algorithm:

1. Create a sliding window or 2 pointers with `left = 0` and `right = N-1`. You could also say a sliding window of `length N`.
2. Keep track of the minimum value of `segment_starts[right] - segment_starts[left]`.
3. Run a loop while `right < len(segment_starts)` and increment `left` and `right` after each iteration.
4. At the end of the loop return `the found min value + 1`.

In pseudo code:

```
# assuming segment_starts is sorted none-decreasing

if N > len(segment_starts): return Infinity
if N < 2: raise Invalid Input Error

left, right = 0, N-1
curr_best = segment_starts[right] - segment_starts[left]
for right < len(segment_starts):
  curr_best = min(curr_best, segment_starts[right] - segment_starts[left])

return curr_best+1
```